# Can't start openvpn server..? Does anybody have an idea where issue lies?

Tags: openvpn, blocking, ufw, systemctl

```
root@debian:/etc/openvpn/server# systemctl status openvpn@server
● openvpn@server.service - OpenVPN connection to server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-10-08 11:51:07 EDT; 20min ago...

root@debian:/etc/openvpn# journalctl -xe
Oct 08 12:42:02 debian sshd[7060]: Invalid user uftp from 179.43.141.99 port 47550
Oct 08 12:42:02 debian sshd[7060]: input_userauth_request: invalid user uftp [preauth]
Oct 08 12:42:02 debian sshd[7060]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Oct 08 12:42:02 debian sshd[7060]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=179.43.1
Oct 08 12:42:04 debian sshd[7060]: Failed password for invalid user uftp from 179.43.141.99 port 47550 ssh2
Oct 08 12:42:04 debian sshd[7060]: Received disconnect from 179.43.141.99 port 47550:11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [pr
Oct 08 12:42:04 debian sshd[7060]: Disconnected from 179.43.141.99 port 47550 [preauth]
Oct 08 12:42:05 debian sshd[7043]: Failed password for root from 218.92.0.200 port 61434 ssh2
Oct 08 12:42:07 debian sshd[7043]: Failed password for root from 218.92.0.200 port 61434 ssh2
Oct 08 12:42:08 debian sshd[7043]: Received disconnect from 218.92.0.200 port 61434:11:  [preauth]
Oct 08 12:42:08 debian sshd[7043]: Disconnected from 218.92.0.200 port 61434 [preauth]
Oct 08 12:42:08 debian sshd[7043]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=218.92.0.200  use
Oct 08 12:42:11 debian kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens192 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:10:5d:55:44:03:a7:a3:92:7c:08:00 SRC=45.143.203.12 DST=176.2
Oct 08 12:42:20 debian kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens192 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:10:5d:55:44:03:a7:a3:92:7c:08:00 SRC=167.248.133.72 DST=176.
Oct 08 12:42:24 debian sshd[7062]: Invalid user cacti from 179.43.141.99 port 36014
Oct 08 12:42:24 debian sshd[7062]: input_userauth_request: invalid user cacti [preauth]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The journalctl output is not helpful here as it does not show the state of OpenVPN.   I might try running Openvpn in the foreground from the command line and seeing what it says.